# C# Linq returning Null or Empty valued properties

Tags: c#, linq, properties

I have looked up the (2) questions found in here, but couldn't translate to my work, which is probably one of the simplest ones. I have a class with properties, which are getting filled by a data read at some early stage. I have the expression below to list all NON-NULL, Non-empty, Non-Whitespace values, but no matter what I do it doesn't work - meaning, returns also empty properties.
(c being an integer):

```
            var props = MyClass.MyApi.Test[c]

            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new { name = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(MyClass.MyApi.Test[c]) })
            .Where
            (
                x => x != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ToString())
            )
            .ToList();
```

And I get, for example

```
{ name = lalala, value = 1 }, { name = aURL, value = http://servertest:7707/table/some/thing }, { name = table_name, value = MY.TABLE }, { name = else, value = }, { name = more, value =  }, { name = myindex, value =  }
```

I just can't rid of properties that have no value, like property `more` above, or `myindex`..
Any advice/help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: `x => x != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.value.ToString())` try doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currenty checking if `x` is not null, but `x` is the full item.
You should check if `x.value` is not null
Like so

```
var props = MyClass.MyApi.Test[c]
.GetType()
.GetProperties()
.Select(x => new { name = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(MyClass.MyApi.Test[c]) })
.Where
(
    x => x.value != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.value.ToString())
)
.ToList();
```

Edit:
as suggested by Andrei15193
The `where` can be a bit cleaner by using

```
.Where
(
   x => x.value is string stringValue ? !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) : x.value != null
)
```

Comment: Should test if value is string rather than do `.ToString()`, `x.value is string stringValue ? !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) : x.value != null`

Comment: @Andrei15193 you are right the code can be optimized even more.

Comment: @ConnorStoop That's brilliant, you are right it worked. Well done and thank you so very much. Just a question, I get the correct `{ name = blahblah value = 123.. }` - is there a way to get just `{ blahblah = 123 }` ? If there is anything more in terms of optimization you can instruct me, I thank you in advance. Great help, and much obliged..

Comment: No, i don't think this is possible. Or do you mean Json format?